# Hierarchy Nested Object with Automapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nested, copy, automapper

I have some problem with the code.
When I try to get a copy of my list, as in the code below, I get a stack overflow exception.

My class:

```
public partial class tbl_Accounts
{
    public tbl_Accounts()
    {
        AccountChilds   = new HashSet<tbl_Accounts>();
        GLLinks         = new HashSet<tbl_SLToGL>();
    }

    public int                          ID                  { get; set; }
    public short                        FK_Year             { get; set; }
    public byte                         FK_Company          { get; set; }
    public int?                         FK_Parent           { get; set; }
    public byte                         LevelAccount        { get; set; }
    public int                          Code                { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string                       Title               { get; set; }
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string                       TitleLatin          { get; set; }
    public byte                         Kind                { get; set; }
    public bool                         IsActive            { get; set; }
    public bool                         HasDL               { get; set; }
    public bool                         HasLevelFour        { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime                     CreatDate           { get; set; }
    public  ICollection<tbl_Accounts>   AccountChilds       { get; set; }
    public  ICollection<tbl_SLToGL>     GLLinks             { get; set; }
    public  tbl_Accounts                AcountsParrent      { get; set; }
}
```

And my configuration mapping code is:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddCollectionMappers();
            cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;

            cfg.CreateMap<tbl_SLToGL, tbl_SLToGL>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ID,             src => src.UseValue(0))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.FK_Year,        src => src.UseValue(Coding.ToYear))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.FK_SL,          src => src.UseDestinationValue());

            cfg.CreateMap<tbl_Accounts, tbl_Accounts>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.FK_Year,        src => src.UseValue(Coding.ToYear))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ID,             src => src.UseValue(0))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.AcountsParrent, src => src.Ignore())
                .ForMember(dest => dest.GLLinks,        src => src.MapFrom(x => x.GLLinks));
        });


        var ListSL = config
                        .CreateMapper()
                        .Map<IList<tbl_Accounts>, IList<tbl_Accounts>>(List);
```

When I run the code I get Exception and Exit the app.
Please help me.

Comment: Becuase I want To Insert All Record From a Year To Next Year. and Insert To Database By Ef 6.OK?

Comment: No this list Have Child Object And Child Objects Have another Child and So   on. it may take 8 level deep.

Comment: Like A Tree List .we Dont know How many children every object have.
I want create a Copy of List For Next Year.

Comment: Try upgrading AM.

Comment: [Deep Copy using AutoMapper](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1107342/Deep-Copy-Using-AutoMapper) may help.